# Use Nokia Lumia 920 / Windows Phone 8 as PC screen on HDMI

Tags: display, hdmi, windows-phone-8

I'm looking for a solution that would allow me to use a WP8 device as PC screen.

I know this is possible to do on Android devices, but I haven't been able to find any app  nor info on how to achieve this on a WP8 device.

Not sure if this is even possible since Nokia Lumia 920 has only micro usb and the normal headphone jack, so I doubt I could connect a hdmi cable to it.

Has anyone seen a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Phone does not have the tecnology to use mini HDMI. But for 99$ you can buy a Bluetooth HDMI i might think will work. You can find it at: http://www.indiegogo.com/projects/airtame-wireless-hdmi-for-everyone--2

Comment: That is a great gadget thanks for sharing! Might really solve my problem.